# Invoke-webrequest doesn't comeout when posting data on server with -InFile flag

Tags: powershell

I am using invoke-webrequest command to load a file on server with POST command, and the file does get loaded. However the command hangs in console until I hit enter.

Here's what I m executing:

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method POST -ContentType $ContentType -Headers $headerHash -InFile $filePath  -TimeoutSec $timeOut

Comment: Also is there a mechanism to debug this scenario

Comment: Yes, just add the `-Debug` parameter

Comment: Debug also not helping much..

Comment: I ran the command with Verbose on, and it ask for confirmation to run the command as below. However when I provided -confirm:$true, invoke-webrequest suggests that there's no confirm command. I am not sure how to proceed. 

Confirm
Continue with this operation?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [H] Halt Command  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):